Map and assign admin roles and custom roles to account level Azure Databricks groups provisioned via SCIM at account level using Terraform
I have enabled SCIM at the account level  and provisioned AAD groups to my Azure Databricks group.I need to create an account level security group and map Databricks admin roles like : 1)Account Admin 2)Marketplace admin 3)Billing admin as well as custom roles to the group.
My script:
provider "databricks" {
  alias = "manager"
  host = "https://account.azuredatabricks.net"
  account_id = "..."
}

resource "databricks_group" "test_group" {
  provider = databricks.manager
  display_name = "test_group_uc"
}

resource "databricks_group_role" "my_group_account_admin"{
  provider = databricks.manager 
  group_id = databricks_group.test_group.id
  role = "account_admin"
}

This works, I am able to assign account_admin role in test_group_uc.
But when I try to assign other admin roles like : workspace_admin or billing_admin , I receive errors as :
Error : cannot create group role : invalidValue Invalid role value workspace_admin
I also require some help to find resources on how to create custom roles.

What is the exact error its showing!

May i know the databricks/databricks provider version youre using @ArghyaGanguly


Admin roles and custom roles to account level Azure Databricks groups provisioned at account level using Terraform

As per the databricks documentation after the 1.210 release of the databricks/databricks provider with an account-level group using the workspace provider and credentials we can be able to provide the necessary roles for groups and service principle.
demo configuration:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "4.12.1"
    
    databricks = {
      source  = "databricks/databricks"
      version = "1.59.0"
    }
  }
}
.
.
provider "databricks" {
  alias      = "manager"
  host       = "https://accounts.azuredatabricks.net"
  account_id = "<YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID>"
}

resource "databricks_service_principal" "sp" {
  application_id       = "<Service Principal ID>"
  display_name         = "vksbapp"
  allow_cluster_create = true
}

resource "databricks_service_principal_role" "account_admin" {
  service_principal_id = databricks_service_principal.sp.id
  role                 = "account_admin"
}

resource "databricks_group" "test_group" {
  provider     = databricks.manager
  display_name = "test_group_uc"
}

resource "databricks_group_role" "my_group_account_admin" {
  provider = databricks.manager
  group_id = databricks_group.test_group.id
  role     = "account_admin"
}

resource "databricks_group_role" "my_group_marketplace_admin" {
  provider = databricks.manager
  group_id = databricks_group.test_group.id
  role     = "marketplace_admin"
}

resource "databricks_group_role" "my_group_billing_admin" {
  provider = databricks.manager
  group_id = databricks_group.test_group.id
  role     = "billing_admin"
}

resource "databricks_group_role" "my_group_custom_role" {
  provider = databricks.manager
  group_id = databricks_group.test_group.id
  role     = "<CUSTOM_ROLE_NAME>"
}

refer:
databricks_group_role | Resources | databricks/databricks | Terraform | Terraform Registry
